# How do I perform a nexted query on django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-related-manager

so i have these 2 model

1. Profile (have one to one relationship with my default django User model)
2. Item  ( also have one to one relationship with my default django User model)
   from Item model, how do i get access to Profile model using User model

please see my code below

My Model

````
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True) ```

My View

def home(request):
   all_item_lists = Item.objects.all()

   context = {
       'all_item_lists':all_item_lists
       }
   return render(request, 'findit/home.html', context)

My Template

{% for list in all_item_lists %}
      <!-- how want to get the phone number of the user that posted this Item -->  
                       <span>{{list.owner.first_name }}</span>                                     
                 {% endfor %}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Profile for a User by using `user.profile`

```
{% for list in all_item_lists %}
    <span>{{ list.owner.profile.phone }}</span>
    <span>{{ list.owner.first_name }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks alot, this solved my problem

Comment: Then mark it as a correct answer it will help the community